# node.js ssh2shell wrapper fails to login to cisco devices

Tags: node.js, ssh

I'm using node to manage some of our cisco devices and am running into an issue which I haven't been able to resolve in last two days.

Using SSH2 module I am able to connect and execute commands on Cisco gear, but that is limiting me to run only one command at a time. For a follow up command it requires me to establish a new connection and then run another command. This does not work for my needs.

Reading up on some of the answers in SO I started using SSH2Shell wrapper for SSH2 as it allows multiple commands to be executed in a sequential order. But using SSH2Shell I am not able to establish a connection to Cisco gear because the Ciphers offered by Client do not match what are supported on Server. I had the same problem with SSH2 module, but I was able to resolve that by adding the Cipher and KEX. When I do the same in SSh2Shell it does not work. I have tried adding them in several different ways and different places, it just wouldn't connect.

I think I am on the right track, I just don't know the right place to add the Ciphers and KEX.

Here is my code for SSH2Shell:

```
var host = {
    server:        {  
            host:         "<host IP>",
            port:         "22",
            userName:     "<username>",
            password:    "<password>"
        },
        connection:         require ('ssh2'),
        commands:      [
            "show version",
            "show ssh"
        ],
        algorithms: {
            kex: [
                'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1',
                'ecdh-sha2-nistp256',
                'ecdh-sha2-nistp384',
                'ecdh-sha2-nistp521',
                'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256',
                'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'],
            cipher: [
                'aes128-ctr',
                'aes192-ctr',
                'aes256-ctr',
                'aes128-gcm',
                'aes128-gcm@openssh.com',
                'aes256-gcm',
                'aes256-gcm@openssh.com',
                'aes256-cbc'
            ]
        },
        msg: {
            send: function( message ) {
            console.log("message: " + message);
            }
        },
    verbose: true,
    debug:               true,
    idleTimeOut:         15000,
    connectedMessage:    "connected",
    readyMessage:        "ready",
    closedMessage:       "closed",

    onCommandComplete: function( command, response, sshObj ) {

        console.log("------------- onCommandComplete ---------");
        console.log(command + ": " + response);
    },
    onEnd: function( sessionText, sshObj ) {
        console.log("--------- onEnd has ------------");
        console.log(sessionText);
    }
};



//Create a new instance 
var SSH2Shell = require ('ssh2shell'),
    SSH       = new SSH2Shell(host);

//Start the process 
SSH.connect();
```

I get 'connected' followed by 'closed' on the terminal when I execute this. Debugging on Cisco Router shows me that my ciphers do not match.

Aug 22 12:06:59: %SSH-3-NO_MATCH: No matching cipher found: client aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm,aes256-gcm@openssh.com server aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I logged an issue on Github for SSH2Shell and thanks to the author "cmp-202" this issue is now resolved. Here is a copy of the script that works in providing Cipher and KEX.
An additional issue was uncovered and resolved in SSH2Shell version 1.5.1, where "keyboard-interactive" event is now implemented. The script below uses both - user defined ciphers and "keyboard-interactive" event:

```
var host = {
   server: {
      host: "<hostname or IP>",
      port: "22",
      userName: "<username>",
      password: "<password>",
      hashMethod:     "md5", 
      readyTimeout: 50000,
      tryKeyboard: true,
      algorithms: {
         kex: [
            'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1',
            'ecdh-sha2-nistp256',
            'ecdh-sha2-nistp384',
            'ecdh-sha2-nistp521',
            'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256',
            'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'],
         cipher: [
            'aes128-ctr',
            'aes192-ctr',
            'aes256-ctr',
            'aes128-gcm',
            'aes128-gcm@openssh.com',
            'aes256-gcm',
            'aes256-gcm@openssh.com',
            'aes256-cbc' ]
         }
      },
      commands: [
         "show deviceport global",
         "show deviceport names" ],
      msg: {
         send: function( message ) {
            console.log("message: " + message);
         }
      },
      verbose: true,
      debug: true,
      idleTimeOut: 10000,
      ["keyboard-interactive"]: function(name, instructions, instructionsLang, prompts, finish){
         console.log('Connection :: keyboard-interactive');
         console.log(prompts);
         finish(["<password>"]);
      },
      onEnd: function( sessionText, sshObj ) {
         sshObj.msg.send("--------- onEnd has ------------");
         sshObj.msg.send(sessionText);
      }

};

//Create a new instance
var SSH2Shell = require ('ssh2shell-ssh2.connect-options'),
SSH = new SSH2Shell(host);

//Start the process
SSH.connect();
```

Hopefully this will save someone some time.

Answer (score 1):

The `ssh2shell` module seems to only pass specific options to `ssh2`, so it will not pass the `algorithms` option on through. You may want to submit an issue to the project's issue tracker about it.

Comment: Thanks mscdex. I'll do that.